# Как правильно создавать прокси в Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring

***У меня есть примерно такой контроллер (все совпадения случайны):***

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/something")
public class SomeController {

    private volatile int someNumber = 10;
    private static final String SECURITY_HEADER = "security";

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Integer> some() {s

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(SECURITY_HEADER, getSecurityCode());

        return new ResponseEntity<> (
                someNumber,
                headers,
                HttpStatus.OK
        );
    }

    @PostMapping
    public int saveNumber(@RequestBody Integer number, @RequestHeader(value = SECURITY_HEADER) String security) {

        if (!getSecurityCode().equals(security)) {
            throw new SecurityException();
        }

        someNumber = number;
        return someNumber;
    }

    private String getSecurityCode() {
        return "You will never guess";
    }

}
```

Мне не нравится, что в приложении приходится много раз писать `ResponseEntity` и прочие однотипные вещи. Можно ли как-то легко воспользоваться аоп-библиотекой спринга и обернуть мой контроллер в прокси. Я хочу получить что-то вроде `MethodInterceptor` спринга. Не могу разобраться как это можно удачно сделать в моем приложении на Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

Если не нужно добавлять заголовки и изменять код ответа, то можно вместо `ResponseEntity<Type>` вернуть просто `Type`.

Для добавления заголовка ко всем ответам можно использовать `OncePerRequestFilter` или `@ControllerAdvice` для добавления чего-то в зависимости от типа, который вернут метод контроллера.